# Xamarin Forms (VS2019) + iOS Intents UI: How to access Assets from Extension (IntentsUI)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, sirishortcuts

I used the Xamarin version of [SoupChef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/ios12-soupchef/) for Siri Intents. I was able to access the Container's Assets from the SoupChefIntentsUI.IntentViewController by requesting the bundle by identifier (using the BundleIdentifier of the main App) and then I just loaded the image by passing the bundle

```
CGSize DisplayOrderConfirmation(Order order, OrderSoupIntent intent, OrderSoupIntentResponse response){
/* unrelated code */

//this line work in the SoupChef example but
//On Xamarin.Forms this returns null
var containerBundle = NSBundle.FromIdentifier("com.something.SoupChef");

//always returns null because it seems it looks into the IntentsUI.Assets
var iconNull = UIImage.FromBundle("AppIcon");

//it returns the icon from the SoupChef.Assets
var iconNotNull = UIImage.FromBundle("AppIcon", containerBundle, configuration: null);

/* unrelated code */
}
```

I was also able to retrieve the AppIcon by creating the NSBundle doing something like this (in case you didn't want to assume that the bundle identifier names don't follow the Apple standard where the Container and the extensions have the same bundle identifier with the exception of the last segment)

```
CGSize DisplayOrderConfirmation(Order order, OrderSoupIntent intent, OrderSoupIntentResponse response){
/* unrelated code */

Class GetClassForType (Type type)
{
    IntPtr myClassHandle = Class.GetHandle (typeToLookup);
    if (myClassHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        return new Class (myClassHandle);
    else
        return null;
}

//this returns the bundle identifier of the SoupChef app 
//(not the SoupChefIntentUI) on the SoupChef example
//on Xamarin.Forms (my project) it returns the IntentsUI identifier
var containerBundle = NSBundle.FromClass(GetClassForType(typeof(SoupChef.OrderIntent)));

//the icon is returned
var icon = UIImage.FromBundle("AppIcon", containerBundle, configuration: null);

/* unrelated code */
}
```

My problem is that I want to do the same thing on a different project that is using Xamarin.Forms, and the two previous ways that worked for me on the SoupChef project don't work here.

Is there a way to access the Assets set on the App.iOS.Assets or do I have to move them to the shared project where I have the models and other things that both the App.iOS and its Extensions are using?

I noticed that the Bindings (the project where the OrderIntent is) in the SoupChef example has the same namespace as the Container App ("SoupChef"), so I assigned the same namespace in my project with Xamarin.Forms and still nothing.

Comment: Images can be loaded from a local file, an embedded resource, downloaded, or loaded from a stream . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#display-images .

Comment: The icons already exist in the Assets, and they have different sizes. So accessing them from there would be ideal so I don't need to manually select the size. This works fine on the SoupChef example but for some reason I can't get it work on Xamarin.Forms :(

Comment: Create a new image set with different name . Or you could re-scale the image in Forms .